# Matching a non-breaking space value in XPath

Tags: xpath

Let's say I have such XML structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How would I specify a comparison with node value in a predicate:

```
//tr/td[.="???"]
```

What should be specified instead of `???`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath 2 you can use

```
//tr/td[. = codepoints-to-string((160))]
```

independent of the tool you use

Answer (score 4):

The solution is

```
//tr/td[.="\u0160"]
```

where actual unicode presentation would depend on the tool you use.

Comment: For those using the nokogiri ruby library, you'll want \u00a0 for hexadecimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the literal value of `&nbsp;`:

```
/table/tr/td[.=' ']
```

Comment: Nope. Space won't match it

Comment: @zerkms - that's not a normal space. that's the literal non-breaking space character.

Comment: how readers are supposed to distinguish it? After copy-pasting I see the `0x20` space character.

Comment: @zerkms It was a literal non-breaking space when I pasted it. Really readers don't need to distinguish it because the answer is really "use the literal value of the entity reference" and is generic.

Comment: "use the literal value of the entity reference" --- without explanation of how to type it - it's not helpful. Compare to my own answer?

Comment: I will. Since there are no other answers that would shed some light on the question.