# How do I search for element with &nbsp; symbol in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

First I thought that element is empty, but I found out it contains:

```
<div class="Tips">&nbsp;</div>
```

which is `NO-BREAK SPACE`. I wanted to catch this div by `xpath` but I am not able to do so. What `xpath` do you use for

```
text()='?'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching a non-breaking space value in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150806/matching-a-non-breaking-space-value-in-xpath)

Comment: you can also use css selector instead of xpath.

Comment: How can I fetch no-break space with css selector? The main reason of this is I need to verify this element contains nothing else, only no-break space.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out, that you have to use:

```
//div[@class='Tips' and text()='\u00a0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
//div[@class='Tips' and text()='${nbsp}']
```

Comment: I found this solution, but this variable needs to be specified in some frameworks. I use Robot framework and it needs to be added directly and not as variable.

Answer (score 0):

In robot framework, the following worked for me:

In the html:

```
<div>
  "Mickey &nbsp; Mouse"
</div>
```

In my test:

```
Element Should Be Visible    xpath=//div[normalizespace(contains(string(),'Mickey Mouse'))]
```

Comment: This answer is not related to question. Main topic was to catch NO-BREAK SPACE and not other symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The only xpath that worked for me was:

```
//span[.=' ']
```